# What is the correct syntax to do a major version upgrade of Aurora Postgres on AWS RDS from the CLI?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am trying to run the following command to upgrade from Postgres 10.14 to 11.9

```
aws rds modify-db-cluster \
--db-cluster-identifier [my db cluster identifier] \
--engine-version 11.9 \
--allow-major-version-upgrade \
--apply-immediately
```

When I try to run it I get the following message:

```
Unknown options: --allow-major-version-upgrade
```

But the documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyDBCluster.html

lists AllowMajorVersionUpgrade as the very first parameter.

What is the correct syntax to do a major version upgrade of Aurora Postgres on AWS RDS from the CLI?

Comment: First, I would look at the CLI documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-cluster.html instead of the raw API documentation to determine the correct CLI syntax. Second, I suggest checking that you have the latest version of the CLI installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Mark B was correct (unfortunately he posted a comment instead of an answer). Upgrading from CLI 1 to CLI 2 fixed the issue.